# Find format used to parse date into string

Tags: c#, .net, datetime, parsing, cultureinfo

```
DateTime date = new DateTime(1970, 1, 15);
string sdate = date.ToString(value_i_will_forget as string,
    CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);

// some lines later

string format_string = MagicParse(sdate,
    CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

I have an arbitrary date that I write to a string with `CulturInfo.InvariantCulture`. The .Net format I use - `"d"`, for example - is now forgotten.

I do know however that the string hasn't changed, its still valid and its still with invariant culture. Im looking for the `MagicParse` function to **extract the format string used to write the formatted date.**

Comment: Are you only allowing standard format strings, or are custom format strings allowed as well?

Comment: Only standard format strings. Actually, even just a subset of the standard formats. Are you suggesting a brute force approach?

Comment: Sort of. I don't know of any built-in methods to do this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unless you have a sample of dates in which the day exceeds 12, then there is no feasible way that this would ever be safe.

Comment: Even though we are able to assume that the format haven't changed?

Comment: Even then you're not certain. A 13 can be either the day or 2013.

Comment: Example: The date is January 1st, 2001. The format strings "MM/dd/yy", "dd/MM/yy", "yy/MM/dd"... all create "01/01/01". How do you reverse engineer that?

Answer (score 0):

`DateTime.Parse(your_date_string, CultureInfo.InvariantInfo)`
, also you can add specific DateTimeStyles in third parameter
Try this one 
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/system.globalization.datetimeformatinfo.shortdatepattern.aspx

Comment: This doesn't give the format string used to parse the DateTime.